# Is "data, in its broader typological sense" correct to use in a sentence?

Tags: meaning, sentence

Through the following sentence :

> ...data, in its broader typological sense,...

I want to mean data with its different types (text, image...)

Is that correct to say? Otherwise what would be an alternative?

Comment: Data scientists call text, web pages, spreadsheets, and images *documents* rather than *data*. Please take a look at this oft-cited paper: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.121.1424&rep=rep1&type=pdf . It discusses the ranking of web pages (Called *documents* in the title). The web pages are considered *data* for the sake of the search engine. If your context is data science, then *documents* will work better than *data*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unlikely that general readers will get your meaning. Unless this is known terminology in the field, there are clearer ways to say what you want.

> data of different types, ...

> data, in its different forms, ...

> In a broader sense data (whether text, images, etc.) ...

Comment: much appreciated ! thanks

Comment: Or you could go old school and say "data, in their different forms..."